# Using where in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I need to know why when I use the statement:

```
local forRaws = "SELECT * FROM "..tokenTable[3].."WHERE subcategory = " .. "'" .. tokenTable[4] .. "'"
```

tokeTable[3] and tokenTable[4] have 2 different string non nil values.
I get a sytax error near =

What am I doing wrong?

Than you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't there be a space before `WHERE`:

```
"SELECT * FROM "..tokenTable[3].." WHERE subcategory = '" .. tokenTable[4] .. "'"
```

?